# GUI with PyGame

Tags: python, user-interface, opengl, pygame, directx

I made a GUI with Python and PyGame and I want to make more futuristic GUI from now on. While making this particular GUI, I found that PyGame may not be the best choice as the number of user events are limited and the drawings have a low quality, what I mean with this is the arcs drawn alongside the stop button in the image, have pixels that are not painted.

What I want to know is:

- Am I mistaken that PyGame is not appropriate for this and should I still use PyGame? - maybe I should not be using drawings and should use images but then loose the ability to change colors.
- Should I learn OpenGL and make my own objects and interactions?
- Maybe Python isn't the most appropriate tool for this, could that tool be C++ and OpenGL or DirectX?

The best thing with using Python is the easiness to make things happen, I created a simple program that gets data from a website and saves it as an CSV file using Pandas. This GUI was made just to show the progress bar and have a start button that executes the main function in another thread so the GUI wont stop.

[image: GUI made with PyGame]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Sprites-and-textures) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/More-tricks-with-sprites), it is probably the quickest setup with DirectX to render GUI. Also checkout samples, maybe there are something about rendering UI there.

DirectX coding is time absorbing really, so is OpenGL 3+, yet DirectX wins with the simplicity of SpriteBatch. On the other hand, OpenGL has legacy bindings for immediate draw, so you could just tell points forming polygons and texture fill them, without buffer creation or anything, but I would stick with DirectX.

Yet you will have to implement user input like hovering over element to show some info, which is also non trivial (requires managing geometry and stuff), think about using some ready-to-go library, like [CEGUI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=iXsZh1owpBI).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that PyGame is not quite what you are looking for, but many people have made very expansive modules for making games in python. Also the fact that python is cross-platform programing language like C is great. The only setback is if you want to make this program standalone. Very few computers come with python 3.6 pre-installed(I am dismissing the fact that MacOS comes with python 2.7 already installed), and many of the modules that allow you to built your script into a standalone app don't support python 3.6.

You could use C++ with OpenGL or DirectX but these tools are a good bit harder to use, now I don't know how advanced you are in coding, and if you would like to make your app for both the MacOS and Windows platforms it would take a lot of work to port the app.

It's up to you and I hope I have helped!

Mr.Zeus